# Create new Mongodb Documents vs Pushing to a Document's Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

A temperature logger records the temperature every 1 second, and using Meteor.js a real time chart shows the temperature averaged over the last 5 seconds.

Is it best practice to save each individual temperature reading as a new Mongodb document? Or push the new reading to an array in a document corresponding to a particular temperature logger?

For the second case, will the Meteor.js client drawing the chart receive the entire document when using `cursor.observeChanges`? If so, wont this can be a huge document with months of temperature data that the client downloads every second?

Comment: It's recommended to save each reading as a new document rather than pushing to an array.  Detailed explanation can be found [`here`](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of data is called time-series and MongoDB has done [a](http://www.mongodb.com/webinar/time-series-1-july-2014) [number](http://www.mongodb.com/webinar/time-series-2-july-2014) [webinars](http://www.mongodb.com/webinar/time-series-3-july-2014) and blog [posts](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb) on the best way to handle this data.

The basic idea is to do a cross between the document-per-measurement and all of the measurements in one document. You create a document that holds all of the measurement for some period of time (say a day). To avoid document moves and "holes" you pre-allocate the document with invalid values (e.g., 0, -1, -infinity) for the measurements.

HTH -
Rob.